# SQL:Comparing two different columns with different data

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, case

I want to get the output based on the following column.
Let me know how should I achieve it.

I have to compare category with `merchantcategory` in where clause.

```
Table A, `Category` (with example data):

Travel              | Gas | Restaurant  | Spending
-------------------------------------------------------
All Other Merchants | gas | Hotel       | Credit Card 
U.S. Post Exchange  | gas | Motel       | Bill Payment


Table B, `MerchantCategory` columns:

College/School Expense
Hospital
Gas
Pre-Authorized Mail/Telephone Order
Hotel/Motel
Shopping
Credit Card Bill Payment
Grossary
All Other Merchants/U.S. Post Exchange
Restaurant
```

So how should I achieve it by adding the separate column as id?

Or by using case or any another way?

Comment: Could you add some sample data? Maybe that would clear things up a bit.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXb3u.jpg

Comment: Pasting a picture of your data isn't very helpful. You want to give other users text that they can copy and paste into an IDE and work on to help you solve your problem. CREATE TABLE statements with INSERT...VALUES will get you better results from the community.

Answer (score 0):

Create a link between each category value, maybe in a temporary table.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CategoryConversions') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #CategoryConversions

CREATE TABLE #CategoryConversions (
    MerchantCategory VARCHAR(100),
    Category VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #CategoryConversions (
    MerchantCategory,
    Category)
VALUES
    ('gas', 'gas'),
    ('Spending', 'Grossary '),
    ('Spending', 'Credit Card Bill Payment'),
    ('Restaurant', 'Hotel/Motel')
    --.....
```

Now join all 3 together:

```
SELECT
    YourWantedColumns
FROM
    TableA AS A
    INNER JOIN #CategoryConversions AS C ON A.Category = C.Category
    INNER JOIN TableB AS B ON C.MerchantCategory = B.MerchantCategory
```

If you want to avoid a temporary table, you can use this approach:

```
;WITH CategoryConversions AS
(
    SELECT
        C.MerchantCategory,
        C.Category
    FROM
        (VALUES 
            ('gas', 'gas'),
            ('Spending', 'Grossary '),
            ('Spending', 'Credit Card Bill Payment'),
            ('Restaurant', 'Hotel/Motel')
            --......
        ) AS C(MerchantCategory, Category)
)
SELECT
    YourWantedColumns
FROM
    TableA AS A
    INNER JOIN CategoryConversions AS C ON A.Category = C.Category
    INNER JOIN TableB AS B ON C.MerchantCategory = B.MerchantCategory
```